# How to import a picture file to an existing psd in Photoshop CS5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to import other picture file to an existing psd in Photoshop frequently. However,  I do only know one complicated way to do this:

1. Open the file with Photoshop.
2. `Windows->Float All in Windows`
3. With Move select the imported file and drag it to the psd file with mouse.

This method require floating all in windows. Are there any other better method to import picture file in Photoshop CS5?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hit File, then select Place. You can select files from the file manager and place them on the canvas.

Comment: cool but it only allows one file at a time. is there a way to import multiple images ?

Comment: Newer versions of Photoshop allow you to drag in files and drop them on the canvas (FINALLY!).

Comment: I sincerely love how Adobe has, after 20 years of owning the entire field of editing photos, neglected to include the feature of choosing a file under its menu for "Import".

Answer (score 4):

In CS5 you should also be able to drag the image file from your explorer (win) or finder (mac) window straight into the Phosothop. I would maximise the canvas PSD file (the file that you wish to place into) first, then drag the file straight into the canvas. This should place the image and activates the document bounding box so that you can resize or rotate the image before you place the file.